# Apache Hadoop- Task process exit with nonzero status of 1

Tags: apache, hadoop

I am new to apache hadoop, I have configured hadoop on my windows xp using cygwin by following the tutorial  http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop. Configuration was suucessfull, but while running a sample program it shows an IOException.

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class TestDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JobClient client = new JobClient();
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(TestDriver.class);
        // TODO: specify output types
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("In"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("Out"));

        // TODO: specify a mapper
        conf.setMapperClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper.class);

        // TODO: specify a reducer
        conf.setReducerClass(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityReducer.class);

        client.setConf(conf);
        try {
            JobClient.runJob(conf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception that I have got,

```
13/11/06 14:54:28 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the 
arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.

13/11/06 14:54:28 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4

13/11/06 14:54:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201311061219_0005

13/11/06 14:54:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%

13/11/06 14:54:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : 
attempt_201311061219_0005_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)


13/11/06 14:54:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : 
attempt_201311061219_0005_m_000006_1, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)
```

The log file is as follows,

```
Meta VERSION="1" .
Job JOBID="job_201311151137_0001" JOBNAME="HadoopTest_TestDriver\.java-5733197832393199007\.jar" USER="akhilkc" SUBMIT_TIME="1384495706421" JOBCONF="hdfs://localhost:9100/tmp/hadoop-SYSTEM/mapred/system/job_201311151137_0001/job\.xml" .
Job JOBID="job_201311151137_0001" JOB_PRIORITY="NORMAL" .
Job JOBID="job_201311151137_0001" LAUNCH_TIME="1384495707234" TOTAL_MAPS="5" TOTAL_REDUCES="1" JOB_STATUS="PREP" .
Task TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_TYPE="SETUP" START_TIME="1384495709875" SPLITS="" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_0" START_TIME="1384495710156" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_0" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495714593" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_1" START_TIME="1384495714625" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_1" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495718234" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_2" START_TIME="1384495718281" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_2" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495721875" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_3" START_TIME="1384495721906" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000006_3" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495725375" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
Task TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000006" TASK_TYPE="SETUP" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495725375" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="" .
Task TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" START_TIME="1384495725390" SPLITS="" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_0" START_TIME="1384495725406" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_0" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495728906" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_1" START_TIME="1384495728937" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_1" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495732531" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_2" START_TIME="1384495732562" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_2" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495736171" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_3" START_TIME="1384495736187" TRACKER_NAME="tracker_notee:localhost/127\.0\.0\.1:1550" HTTP_PORT="50060" .
MapAttempt TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="attempt_201311151137_0001_m_000005_3" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495739781" HOSTNAME="tracker_notee" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" .
Task TASKID="task_201311151137_0001_m_000005" TASK_TYPE="CLEANUP" TASK_STATUS="FAILED" FINISH_TIME="1384495739781" ERROR="java\.io\.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1\.
    at org\.apache\.hadoop\.mapred\.TaskRunner\.run(TaskRunner\.java:425)
" TASK_ATTEMPT_ID="" .
Job JOBID="job_201311151137_0001" FINISH_TIME="1384495739781" JOB_STATUS="FAILED" FINISHED_MAPS="0" FINISHED_REDUCES="0" .
```

Task log I found at localhost:50030/jobtasks.jsp?jobid=job_201311151723_0002&type=setup&pagenum=1&state=killed ,

```
java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)
```

Comment: check the logs of the task. There you should find more detailed information about what went wrong.

Comment: I have gone through the logs, but still I cant understand the error..

Comment: Are there any logs for the task that failed? If so, please paste them in here so that we can help you.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for your valuable attention, I have updated the question with log file.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the log from the task that failed. If you click in the jobtrack web UI on the job that fails, click on "map" and you will find a list of the tasks that have been started. Then click on on Task ID that failed an have a look at the task logs from "Task Logs" -> "All". Just in case you have not done this already. (The web UI may be a little different depending on the version of hadoop you are using.)

Comment: @Fred, This is the error that I have got on my log file, cant find any other log.

Comment: one more try: on the host where your jobtracker is running: open the following url in a browser or curl or the like: http://localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp Try to see if you can find the job you started, from there proceed as I commented above. If there is no jobtracker web ui, try to find more logs on the nodes. I think it will be hard to find the problem without more information from other log files.

Comment: @Fred, I have updated the log that I have got.
I am new to hadoop, can you suggest any site that helps to configuring hadoop on windows and learn hadoop.

Comment: no, not really. personally i would go for a linux vm :)

Answer (score 0):

because the JVM stack size was too small, change your MR JVM stack size

```
# cat /var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/userlogs/job_201507091122_0015/attempt_201507091122_0015_m_000005_3/stdout

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
```

because the JVM stack size was too small, change your MR JVM stack size, fg:
mapred.child.java.opts  -> -Xms2048M -Xmx4096M